# Unable to find local grunt on Centos

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, centos

When attempting to deploy grunt on CentOS, I'm receiving the error:
**"Unable to find local grunt"**.

I tried the suggested: `npm install -g grunt` but I receive the error
**"npm command not found"**. This is odd because I have npm-3.10.8-1.6.9.1.4.el7.x86_64 already installed and it's the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **npm** to your path,
in windows you can do it like that :

```
setx PATH="%PATH%;C:\npmInsFolder"
```

In linux:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/opt/npmInsFolder
```

or:

```
PATH=~/opt/npmInsFolder:$PATH
```

Comment: I tried the suggested commands, both PATH=~/opt/npmInsFolder:$PATH and PATH=~/opt/npmInsFolder:$PATH but I'm still receiving the message "Fatal erro: Unable to find local grunt."

Comment: Do `npm install grunt`